# Google Dataflow error on setup with no information

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm attempting to run a Beam pipeline that has a `requirements.txt` file. This fails and the logging entry, under `worker-startup` is:

```
{
 insertId:  "3570218088494260896:493966:0:74068"  
 jsonPayload: {
  line:  "boot.go:134"   
  message:  "Failed to install packages: failed to install requirements: exit status 1"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "3570218088494260896"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "jumps-cafc68e2-10261505-b789-harness-kn3b"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_type:  "instance"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id:  "2017-10-26_15_05_55-17840030900137737069"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name:  "jumps-cafc68e2"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region:  "global"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/sixty-capital/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker-startup"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2017-10-26T22:12:41.061522503Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "2017-10-26_15_05_55-17840030900137737069"    
   job_name:  "jumps-cafc68e2"    
   project_id:  "sixty-capital"    
   region:  "global"    
   step_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity:  "CRITICAL"  
 timestamp:  "2017-10-26T22:12:35Z"  
}
```

Is there a way of learning more about what happened?

Comment: I think it's an issue that my `requirements.txt` file points to a repo only my local machine has access to. But I also see the local job packaging that repo (and all other dependencies) up and loading them into a GCS bucket. 

What's the point of doing that if the server then downloads them again from PyPI / the original source?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs from the same process immediately prior show what the process was attempting to do.

In this case, the local process had created tarballs / zip files of packages from `requirements.txt` and uploaded them to GCS. The remote process installs `requirements.txt` with a link to those files - this generally allows the installation to avoid downloading anything further.

But if an item in the file is a source that the remote process can't access (either a local path, or a private git repo) rather than a simple package name, the installation fails.